# python google scholar api network

Tags: python, google-scholar

Why do I get the following error in python?

```py
import scholar_network as sn
sn.scrape_single_author(scholar_id='ZmwzVQUAAAAJ', scholar_name='Michelle Duong')
# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scholar_network'
```

Why can't you find the module 'scholar_network'?

Comment: Did you install the package correctly? `pip install scholar-network`

Answer (score 0):

Install the package

```
pip install scholar-network
```

If you did, I assume that you use IDE, and virtual environment in it can be broken.

Try to run it with console

```
python name_of_the_file.py
```

Or try to make a new project with new virtual environment with your hands.